# javascript prototype creating a new user interface element object

Tags: javascript, prototype

i want to create javascript object that can be reused for making complex user interface for web application i have created an javascript object by using prototype this above example works fine. bt not perfect to use.

```
var MainWindow = function(width, height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.html = '';

MainWindow.prototype = {

    toString: function(){
        this.html += '<div id="main_div" style="width:' + this.width + 'px; height:' + this.height + 'px; background-color:#CCC;"></div>';
        return this.html;
    }
}

var newWindow = new MainWindow(400,400);
document.write(newWindow);
```

Now initializing and creating a new object this works fine. bt it cannot be used the way i want

---

now i have created another example for this purpose:-

```
var Button(text){
    this.text = text;
    this.element = '';
}

Button.prototype = {
    this.element = document.createElement("button");
    this.element.innerHTML = this.text;
    return this.element;
}


var x = document.getElementById("main_div");
element = new Button("ashish");
x.appendChild(element);
```

The second example is wrong and doesnot work something is missing there so how can i make it work. and create a new element and append in the way i am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Button = function(text){
    this.text = text;
    this.element = '';
}

Button.prototype.createButton = function()
{
    this.element = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    this.element.innerHTML = this.text;
    return this.element;
}
var x = document.getElementById("main_div");
element = new Button("ashish"); // your Button should be function object
element=element.createButton(); // you should call the property you added
x.appendChild(element);
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/NcsG8/)

Comment: But how can i create and return element default just like in example 1st where string is beign returned

Comment: call newWindow.toString();